# curl in command in elastic search, error mesage 404 does not make sense

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, curl

I types the following command in a linux terminal:

curl -XGET http://something_here.net:5005

i get:
    var hashRoute = '/app/kibana';
    var defaultRoute = '/app/kibana';

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.length) {
  window.location = hashRoute + hash;
} else {
  window.location = defaultRoute;
```

then i try: 
curl -XGET http://something_here.net:5005/_all/_mappings

I get:
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

I try to write the same command in Elastic Search (ES automatically removes key word  and replaces  by ). i DO receive results!

```
{
  "statistic-[...]": {
    "mappings": {
      "statistic": {
        "properties": {
```

[...]

How come i do not get the same results via curl in Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your URL http://something_here.net:5005 is pointing to your Kibana web console. This is not your elasticsearch API, which will be somewhere else. Port 9200 by default.